# Would the Formation of Benzaldehyde Be Possible Under Specific Conditions?

Tags: organic-chemistry, aromatic-compounds, photochemistry

[image]
[image: Chemicals Present in Our Process and Identified Contaminants]

Our process:
We cure an epoxy resin using SLA. The triarylsulfonium hexafluoroantimonate salts in propylene carbonate act as the photoinitiator for the oligomeric reactions between 4,4 isopropylidenedicyclohexanol and 1 chloro 2,3 epoxypropane to crosslink the resin. We then rinse the part in propylene carbonate multiple times, rinse in water once, and finally end with time in the post-curing apparatus. We were finding that the piece was not biocompatible so we turned to further testing.

We sent a cured and cleaned sample in for 24 hour extraction at 37C and tested the extract with GCMS (results on table). The uncured resin itself was also tested and found positive for propylene carbonate and cyclopentanol.

My question is specifically about the benzaldehyde that is present. Would benzaldehyde be able to form using the listed chemicals (and exposure to UV light) or would it likely be introduced from an outside contaminant?

Thanks